# Trying to create odd irregular shaped button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I am trying to create a keypad using Android Grid Layout.  I would like one button that  spans columns and rows in a 'L' Shape, for the Enter key.

[image: Keypad with L shaped Enter button]

See diagram.  I have created a keypad and added the numeric buttons using Grid layout ok, but am struggling to work out if it is possible to span the rows and columns as I want to create the Enter Key.
Is this possible?
 any hints tips or example code would be appreciated

Comment: Can you not create two buttons one below 9 and one right of 9 . These two button will be bind to same action but in your look and feel of grid they would look like enter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more elegant solution would be to create your buttons dynamically drawing filled touchable polygons on a canvas.

Take a look at "ImageMap for Android" (http://catchthecows.com/?p=113). It is really powerful, you can even create touchable charts.

Comment: But this would be more expensive in terms of memory, cpu usage, harder to implement... don't you?

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty workaround: create a button (return) which is as big as 4 (2*2) of the regular ones.

Then put button 9 over it, top lef aligned.

It will work just fine

Comment: not the most elegant solution, but probably the easiest way to do it.

Comment: I wouldn't call it elegant, but at least it's: easy, fast, cheap, light... ;)